# Python Bottle window.location.href Unresponsive

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, server, bottle

I am trying to write code that would rotate a servo motor with the buttons on a small RaspberryPi web server.

I am using python and the module Bottle for the HTML. I have been working on this for a while, and the best I can get is the buttons redirecting to '/false'.

I believe the error may be with the "window.location.href/", but I'm not certain.

The issue is I don't know where the error is, honestly, any help would be appreciated I've made little to no progress over the last couple of hours.

```
def locking_status(status):
    if status == 'open':
        return 'Unlocked'
    else:
        return 'Locked'

def html_for_button(status,title):
    result = "<input type='button' onClick='changed("+status+")' value='"+title+"'/>"
    print(result)
    return result

@route('/')
@route('/<status>')
def index(status = 'open'):
    if status == 'open':
        servo.angle = 90
    else:
        servo.angle = -90

    response = "<script>"
    response += "function changed(status)"
    response += "{"
    response += "  window.location.href='/' + status"
    response += "}"
    response += "</script>"

    response += '<h1>GPIO Control</h1>'
    response += html_for_button('open', 'UNLOCK')
    response += html_for_button('closed', 'LOCK')

    response += '<h2>Door=' + locking_status(status) + '</h2>'

    return response

run(host='MY_IP', port = 80, debug = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be over complicating things.  Also I would really look into using bottle's built in template engine.  It is quite powerful.

```
from bottle import get, run, template

@get('/')
@get('/<status>')
def index(status = 'open'):
    if status == 'open':
        servo.angle = 90
        stat = 'Unlocked'
    else:
        servo.angle = -90
        stat = 'Locked'

    response = '''<script>
    function changed(status)
    {
      window.location.href='http://localhost/' + status
    }
    </script>

    <h1>GPIO Control</h1>
    <input type='button' onClick='changed("open")' value='Open'/>
    <input type='button' onClick='changed("closed")' value='Closed'/>
    <h2>Door= {{stat}}</h2>
    '''
    return template(response, stat=stat)

run(host='0.0.0.0', port = 80, debug = True)
```